# Starting Azure Emulator - Access denied

Tags: azure

I have a problem when I try to debug my Azure web worker role. During startup I get the following error:

[image: Error message while starting Azure emulator]

When I run Visual Studio 2015 (update 3) from an elevated account, then it does work. I cannot recall major configuration changes. I have only configured some URL ACLs (netsh http ... urlacl). Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: I always have to run VS as elevated for mine to work.

Comment: It shouldn't be required to run VS in elevation mode (since Azure SDK v2.1), when you use the Emulator Express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reinstalled the Azure SDK (v2.9.1) and everything works fine again.